# How to prevent system from gettin Freezed on launching any software?

Tags: freeze, system

I'm using a computer system with the following system specification:

```
System:        HP-Compaq-dc7100-SFF-DX878AV
Memory:        1GB
Processor:     Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz x 2
Graphics:      Intel 915Gx86/MMX/SSE2
OS type:       32-bit
Disk:          16.4GB
```

This specification is far more than specified on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Page.

But my system often gets hanged/freeze. This is very annoying. What might be the problem?

I haven't installed any heavy software like 'Krita Image Editor' or 'Nebteans IDE'.

Even if when I just start my computer it's resources normally used are as follow:

```
Memory: 550 MB
CPU:    aoubt 60% to 80%
```

Why is it so high usage of resources? Can any one help about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is too heavy for this old computer.

I would suggest installing [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) 14.04.

1 GB of RAM is just enough. And Ubuntu graphical effects drain all CPU and GPU resources.

Minimal requirements just let OS start and work some way. They do not guarantee any comfortable work.

Comment: As far as I got, you are suggesting me to install Ubuntu 14.04, I'm also talking about Ubuntu 14.04, It's not working well on this system

Comment: I am suggesting not Ubuntu, but Lubuntu. It is much lighter. http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: oh, sorry. I didn't looked carefully, It seemed you suggested me Ubuntu, thanks for the suggestion for Lubuntu :-)